# RAM module compatibility between two similar MacBook's

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

If a RAM module is removed from one MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) and inserted into another one of the same model, will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the models are exactly same, **Yes**.